# Using the same class method internally and via JSON in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller, I want to use the same code both internally from other methods in the class and externally via JSON. Is it possible to combine these into a single method?

Currently, I'm defining two class methods, one being a thin wrapper around the other, like so:

```ruby
class TestController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def foo_external
    respond_with foo_internal
  end

  def some_other_method
    ...
    q = foo_internal
    ...
  end

  private

  def foo_internal
    return {
      :a => 1,
      :b => 2,
    }
  end

end
```

From other methods in the same class, I call `foo_internal`, but from JavaScript I call `foo_external` to return the result as JSON. Is it possible to combine these into a single method `foo`? Something like this:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def foo
    r = {
      :a => 1,
      :b => 2,
    }
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { return r }
      format.js { respond_with r }
    end
  end

  def some_other_method
    ...
    q = foo
    ...
  end

end
```

This code works when some_other_method is generating an HTML response, but fails when some_other_method trying to generate a JSON response.

I'm using Rails 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be possible. From a friend:

> You can't combine these into one method because foo_external is being
>   called as an action (expected to generate an HTTP response) and
>   foo_internal is being called as part of a different action. If you try
>   to call foo_external from any other action, you'll be asking Rails to
>   generate two competing HTTP responses.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is a little longer, but should do the job now:

```
def foo
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {return {:a => 1, :b => 2}}
    format.js {return {:a => 1, :b => 2}}
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the error I'm getting: "respond_to takes either types or a block, never both".

Comment: I don't think so, Chris. I clarified the problem.